# Twitter Ruby Gem - get friends names and ids, nothing more

Tags: ruby, twitter, twitter-gem

Is it possible to simply get the people you are following with just an id and full name? I do not need any of the additional data, it's a waste of bandwidth.

Currently the only solution I have is:

```
 twitter_client = Twitter::Client.new
 friend_ids = twitter_client.friend_ids['ids']
 friends = twitter_client.users(friend_ids).map { |f| {:twitter_id => f.id, :name => f.name} }
```

is there anyway to just have users returned be an array of ids and full names? better way of doing it than the way depicted above? preferably a way to not filter on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `users` method uses the [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) API call. As you can see on the page, the only param available is `include_entities`. The [only other method](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/search) which helps you find users has the same limitation. So you cannot download only the needed attributes.

The only other thing I'd like to say is that you could directly use the friends variable, I don't see any benefit of running the map on it.

Comment: @randombits did you figure this out? because I'm still haveing trouble with how to write the code out, to get the ids and names.